# Which distro supports more packages? Arch or Debain-based?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, arch-linux, debian-installer, distributions

Since there is no apt in Arch Linux I'm hesitant to use it because most packages have either rpm or deb extensions. Are there a lot more  packages packaged for Arch Linux than there are for a Debian-based distro like Ubuntu?

Comment: The important thing here is not so much how many packages a given distribution includes, but whether it contains packages for the applications you want to install and use.

Comment: Any answer to this is likely to be misleading in one way or another.  Archlinux makes user's own contributions much more prominent through [AUR packages](https://aur.archlinux.org/).  Eg: I myself publish my own packages as dpkg, I've found at least one quietly turning up on Arch.  Whether packages are available through the *central repositories* is completely different to whether they are available.

Comment: Hard to understand why an objective question which simply asks which distro supports more packages, can be opinion based. People shouldn't abuse the close vote feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://repology.org Arch Linux has the largest number of packages among all Linux distros. Debian leads by the number of non-unique packaged projects.

[image: Repology snapshot of 2020-06-30]